# Add library through Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to add ProgressWheel componenent from Todd Davis through Gradle:
https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel

Everything works fine, but now, I have 2 icons in my cel when I run it.

In the installation notes, it says:

--> Using as a library project

To use it as a library in Android Studio, please edit build.gradle.

Modify:

apply plugin: 'android'
Into:

apply plugin: 'android-library'

It seems simple, thing is I don't have access to my files to make this modification!

How should I do???

Comment: Somehow you changed your ApplicationId inside build.graddle. Now you have two applications on your phone. Can you post your build.gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To use it as a library in Android Studio, please edit build.gradle.

That seems to be out of date. The `build.gradle` file already is using the library form of the plugin.

What you are experiencing is the result of manifest merging. The library has an `<activity>` element in its manifest, and you need to get rid of that.

To do this, add the following to your `<application>` element:

```
<activity
  android:name="com.todddavies.components.progressbar.main"
  tools:node="remove" >
</activity>
```

Note that this will require you to add the `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` namespace declaration to your `<manifest>` element.

The `tools:node="remove"` says "hey, some lower-priority manifest is trying to add this `<activity>`; please get rid of it".